# Keycloak Docker Postgres with IPv6 UnknownHostException

Tags: java, docker, ip, keycloak

I'm attempting to create a Docker container using `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1` image the that will connect to a Postgres Database listening on IPv6. Working with a downloaded zip of Keycloak, the application is able to make a connection if I export JAVA_OPTS as follows:

`$ export JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true`

If I attempt to do the same within Docker, however, I receive java.net.UnknownHostException. I've tried both the hostname which should resolve, as well as the IP that is behind the hostname.

If I try to use the IP within the Docker container, I receive:

`Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable`

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, thanks!

UPDATE: This seems to extend beyond just Keycloak, I’ve attempted connecting to the same DB via container using both Spring Boot and Quarkus and receive the same error.

Comment: I would say that's a problem of container, not a Keycloak. Please share docker configuration `docker info`. How did you start Keycloak container? Did you enable IPv6 for Docker daemon https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/ ?

Comment: It seems to be for sure, I’ve tried connecting to the same database with both quarkus and spring boot via container and get the same error. Yes I have ipv6 enabled on the daemon. I think that’s more for listening on IPv6 than anything, however.

Comment: You can try stupid workaround: start container in the host network explicitly, not in default network.